# PHP file unable to extract and split image from database after made changes to the file

Tags: php, database, content-management-system

I have this issue on one of servers, Up until last week, the feed it was pulling the content from was working fine. Now suddenly since last few days, when I made the change to extract category field from database since then it is not extracting the image from the feed but is able to extract all of other content. (This server was set up by previous developer).

I keep getting this error:

going to get file 2020-07-23T15:41:05

going to put /var/www/SpanishMix/

!! problem getting remote file ( 2020-07-23T15:41:05 ) in checkNGet ** trying replace , digiv/2105318.jpg

This is the code in php file:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(90);
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');

$xurl = 'feedlink.com/feed/getXML.php';
$locs = 'server ip';
$locvid = '/var/www/SpanishMix/';

function decrypto($inStr)
{
    $key = '';
    $encrypted = $inStr;
    $decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
    return $decrypted;
}

function dis($v)
{
    echo "<pre>\n";
    print_r($v);
    echo "\n</pre>\n<hr>\n";
}

// --------------------- grab XML
$c = file_get_contents($xurl);
if (strlen($c) < 100) {
    exit('couldnt get data from CMS');
}

// --------------------- parse into usable array of objects
$sa = array();
$ta1 = explode('_ENDI_', $c);
foreach ($ta1 as $i) {
    $ta2 = explode('_ENDF_', $i);
    if ((strlen($ta2[0]) > 4) && (strlen($i) > 200)) {
        $to = new stdClass();
        $to->uid = $ta2[0];
        $to->vurl = "";
        $to->body = $ta2[1];
        $to->people = trim($ta2[2]);
        $to->headline = trim($ta2[3]);
        $to->category = trim($ta2[4]);
        $to->abstract = trim($ta2[5]);
        $to->pubdate = trim($ta2[7]);

        $to->storyid = trim($ta2[6]);

        $to->iurl = trim($ta2[8]);

        $tmpia = explode('.com/', $to->iurl);
        $to->cpi = $tmpia[1];
        $to->iloc = 'http://' . $locs . '/SpanishMix/' . $tmpia[1];

        // code for durability date   
        $tmpda = explode('-', $to->pubdate);
        $oldy = $tmpda[0];
        $newy = $oldy + 1;
        $newys = str_replace($oldy, $newy, $to->pubdate);
        $to->durdate = $newys;

        $to->gotv = 0;
        $to->fs = 0;
        if ($to->uid > 10000) {
            $sa[$to->uid] = $to;
        }
    }
}
dis($sa);

// --------------------- scan vids dir, parse into array including filesize
$va = array();
$dir = $locvid . "*.jpg";
foreach (glob($dir) as $file) {
    $tv = new stdClass();
    $tv->fn = $file;
    $tv->s = filesize($file);
    array_push($va, $tv);
}
dis($va);

// --------------------- check through stories array structure marking those already with video 
$vtg = '';
$itg = '';
$uidtg = '';

// loop through each story
foreach ($sa as $s) {
    $found = 0;
    foreach ($va as $v) {
        // hack out matchable filename from video and story arrays
        $tfn = '/var/www/SpanishMix/' . $s->cpi;
        if ($tfn == $v->fn) {
            $found = 1;
        }
    }
    // if outer looop variable says no video found for this story, make this storey's video URL next to get
    if (!$found) {
        echo "<br>setting itg to $s->iurl<br>\n";
        $itg = $s->iurl;
        $uidtg = $s->uid;
    }
}

echo "<hr><h1> getting video part</h1><br><br>";
// --------------------- elect first story entry with no file
if ($itg) {
    // split img url to take 
    $ifa = explode('.com/', $itg);
    $itg = $itg;
    $outfile = '/var/www/SpanishMix/' . $ifa[1];
    echo "\n<br><b>going to get file $itg<br>going to put $outfile</b><br>\n";

    $remoteFile = file_get_contents($itg);
    if (!$remoteFile) {
        echo "!! problem getting remote file ( $itg ) in checkNGet\n\n";
    } else {
        $res = file_put_contents($outfile, $remoteFile);
        if ($res) {
            echo "put remote image file ( $outfile ) success !\n\n\n";

            // NOW COPY LOCAL FILE TO FUNNY FILENAME
            $cpifn = '/var/www/SpanishMix/digiv/' . $uidtg . '.jpg';
            echo "* about to copy $outfile to $cpifn\n\n";
            copy($outfile, $cpifn);
        } else {
            echo "put remote image file ( $outfile ) fail :( \n\n\n<br><br>";
        }
    }
} 

$tt = '';

$tm = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
       <videonews>
        <news>
        <name>BBCC**storyid**</name>
        <title>**headline**</title>
        <subtitle>**abstract**</subtitle>
        <text>**body**</text>
        <keywords>**people**</keywords>
        <date>**pubdate**</date>
        <durability>**durdate**</durability>
        <category>**category**</category>
        <subcategory>Famosos</subcategory>

        <image>
            <file format="image">**iloc**</file>
        </image>
      </news>
     </videonews>
     ';

$tb = '';

$out = $tt;

foreach ($sa as $s) {
    if ($s->uid == $uidtg) {
        $tfn = "$locs/SpanishMix/" . $tfna[3];
        $tmpt = str_replace('**body**', $s->body, $tm);
        //$tmpt = str_replace('**vidfs**', $s->fs, $tmpt);
        $tmpt = str_replace('**headline**', $s->headline, $tmpt);
        $tmpt = str_replace('**people**', $s->people, $tmpt);
        $tmpt = str_replace('**abstract**', $s->abstract, $tmpt);
        $tmpt = str_replace('**storyid**', $s->storyid, $tmpt);
        $tmpt = str_replace('**category**', $s->category, $tmpt);
        $tmpt = str_replace('**pubdate**', $s->pubdate, $tmpt);
        $tmpt = str_replace('**durdate**', $s->durdate, $tmpt);
        $tmpt = str_replace('**iloc**', $s->iloc, $tmpt);

        $copyA2 = explode('SpanishMix/', $s->iloc);
        $copyImageFN = $copyA2[1];
        $copyNewImageFN = 'digiv/' . $uidtg . '.jpg';
        echo "\n ** trying replace $copyImageFN, $copyNewImageFN\n";
        $tmpt = str_replace($copyImageFN, $copyNewImageFN, $tmpt);

        $out .= "$tmpt\n\n";
    }
}
$out .= $tb;

if ($uidtg) {
    echo "</pre><TEXTAREA cols='120' rows='80'>$out</TEXTAREA>\n";
    echo "<hr>";

    $ox = '/var/www/SpanishMix/digiv/' . $uidtg . '.xml';
    $written = file_put_contents($ox, $out);
    echo "\nALSO putting : xml to $ox [", $written, "]<br>\n";

} else {
    echo "\n NO UIDTG [", $uidtg, "] ! \n not putting any files";
}
```

I would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Could you print out the `$itg` variable before this code `$remoteFile = file_get_contents($itg);` And check is the file path & name correct, and check is such file really exists on the server?

Comment: Hi @AlisherGafurov this is what I am seeing: 
These are some previous images but new ones after 22 July, those are not there, they are not getting saved into this folder: var/www/SpanishMix 


    [75] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fn] => /var/www/SpanishMix/imgjpgf6ef922571f7787b0171d7bab24d561829021565.jpg
            [s] => 56323
        )

setting itg to 2020-07-27T16:42:00
setting itg to 2020-07-27T16:42:00
setting itg to 2020-07-27T16:42:00

I have checked the file and name of folder which are correct, but it's weird about itg setting to date.